# google apps script counting characters in a cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, string-length

I am trying to find a way to adjust a merged cell group to show all text characters that were contained in the first cell when merged.  I thought there would be a simple way to count the number of characters in that first cell and then I can adjust the height of a cell or cells by developing a formula (such as add .2 for each 30 characters).

I am using the following code to try and count the characters:

```
var tempValue;
var tempCount = 0;

    tempValue = sprintSheet.getRange("D3").getDisplayValue();
    tempCount = tempValue.length();
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error on the last line:

> TypeError: Cannot call property length in object

I can't seem to make the transition from range / value to text to use the length property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer

`Use  tempCount = tempValue.length` instead of  `tempCount = tempValue.length();`

## Explanation

Google Apps Script is based on JavaScript. The getDisplayValue() returns an a JavaScript string primitive. A primitive data type can use the the length property, and its called by using `.length`, (note that parenthesis are not used).

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview

Answer (score 1):

The string length is available as a property rather than as a function call.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp

```
tempCount = tempValue.length;
```